# Как управлять сервером с помощью Python?

Tags: python, сервер, pyqt, pyside

Имеется несколько серверов в локалке на win serv 2008,16, есть ли возможность перезапускать их, или выключать Python'ом?

Имею небольшой опыт с QML и Pyside/Pyqt, интерфейс не проблема, главное функционал.
Может быть существуют библиотеки, которые позволяют так делать? Спасибо.

Не особо интересуют сторонние утилиты, суть цели по большей цели в практике питона.

Comment: ваш вопрос не очень понятен. Покажите минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который у вас есть. Что вы уже успели попробовать?

Comment: Пока это только идея, и это лишь просто вопрос о реализации. Но допустим есть доменный сервер, который находится в соседнем кабинете, я могу через рдп на него зайти, управлять. Вопрос лишь в том, могу я перегрузить его питом?

Comment: можете:
subprocess.check_call('reboot')
например так

Comment: А почему не использовать для этих целей Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код который выключит сервер через 60 секунд

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/s", "/t", "60"])
```

Comment: Безусловно спасибо. Но как указать к какому серверу я обращаюсь?

Comment: @Wyles нужно написать интерфейс для сервера на питоне, вывести его на какой нибудь порт и стучаться по этому интерфейсу к питон скрипту (API), который выполнит эту команду, реализация данного вопроса зависит от обстоятельств, целей и ваших предпочтений. А ответ на него выходит за рамки ответа на stackoverflow. Приятного чтения документаций и книг.

Comment: Как вариант можно посмотреть в сторону Flask